# Browse Button Store Path as Variable for Use Elsewhere

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I've found a lot of documentation for how to assign a path to a variable with the open file dialog, but I have been able to figure out how to do it for more complex scenarios involving buttons with Add_Click events in Powershell.

Some background: I'm writing an application that basically converts PDFs to .txt.

My goal is for the user to choose the PDF with an open file dialog after pressing a "browse" button. Once they've grabbed the pdf, I want the OK button to accept the path as a variable and, voila, convert the selected PDF into a .txt file. In other words, I don't want them entering the path on their own; I want the browse button to prompt the open file dialog, and thereafter, have the ability to use the selected path as a variable.

Here's the full code:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
$MainForm = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$okButton = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$cancelButton = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox]$pictureBox1 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$Label = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]$openFileDialog1 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$BrowseButton = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]$button1 = $null
function InitializeComponent
{
$resources = Invoke-Expression (Get-Content "C:\Users\eakinsa\Desktop\Style Guide Report\Includes\Form1.resources.psd1" -Raw)
$okButton = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button)
$cancelButton = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button)
$pictureBox1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox)
$Label = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label)
$openFileDialog1 = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog)
$BrowseButton = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button)
([System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize]$pictureBox1).BeginInit()
$MainForm.SuspendLayout()

#
#BrowseDialog Button
#


$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    Multiselect = $false # Multiple files can be chosen
    Filter = 'PDFs (*.pdf)|*.pdf' # Specified file types
}


$BrowseButton.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Popup
$BrowseButton.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]16,[System.Int32]212))
$BrowseButton.Name = [System.String]'BrowseButton'
$BrowseButton.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$BrowseButton.TabIndex = [System.Int32]1
$BrowseButton.Text = [System.String]'Browse'
$BrowseButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$BrowseButton.Add_Click({$Dialog = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog(); if($Dialog -eq 'OK') {return $FileBrowser.SelectedPath}}) 



#
#cancelButton-Cancel
#
$cancelButton.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Crimson
$cancelButton.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]545,[System.Int32]439))
$cancelButton.Name = [System.String]'cancelButton'
$cancelButton.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$cancelButton.TabIndex = [System.Int32]2
$cancelButton.Text = [System.String]'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$cancelButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true

#
#okButton-Okay
#
$okButton.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::ForestGreen
$okButton.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]626,[System.Int32]440))
$okButton.Name = [System.String]'okButton'
$okButton.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$okButton.TabIndex = [System.Int32]3
$okButton.Text = [System.String]'OK'
$okButton.Add_Click({echo $File })
$okButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true

#
#pictureBox1
#

$pictureBox1.Image = ([System.Drawing.Image]$resources.'pictureBox1.Image')
$pictureBox1.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]12,[System.Int32]12))
$pictureBox1.Name = [System.String]'pictureBox1'
$pictureBox1.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]689,[System.Int32]165))
$pictureBox1.SizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::Zoom
$pictureBox1.TabIndex = [System.Int32]2
$pictureBox1.TabStop = $false
$pictureBox1.add_Click($pictureBox1_Click)
#
#Label
#
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$Label.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
$Label.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]13,[System.Int32]184))
$Label.Name = [System.String]'Label'
$Label.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]570,[System.Int32]13))
$Label.TabIndex = [System.Int32]3
$Label.Text = [System.String]'Use this tool to get a custom report that flags potential style errors in a PDF based on the Elsevier style guide.'
#

#MainForm
#
$MainForm.ClientSize = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]713,[System.Int32]475))
$MainForm.Controls.Add($BrowseButton)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($Label)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($pictureBox1)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($cancelButton)
$MainForm.Controls.Add($okButton)
$MainForm.Font = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList @([System.String]'Segoe UI',[System.Single]8.25,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point,([System.Byte][System.Byte]0)))
$MainForm.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::ForestGreen
$MainForm.Name = [System.String]'MainForm'
$MainForm.Text = [System.String]'PDF Style Reporting Tool'
([System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize]$pictureBox1).EndInit()
$MainForm.ResumeLayout($false)
$MainForm.PerformLayout()
$MainForm.ShowDialog()
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name base -Value $base -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name okButton -Value $okButton -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name pictureBox1 -Value $pictureBox1 -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name Label -Value $Label -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name openFileDialog1 -Value $openFileDialog1 -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name BrowseButton -Value $BrowseButton -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $MainForm -Name button1 -Value $button1 -MemberType NoteProperty
}
. InitializeComponent
```

The code that needs to be modified involves the $FileBrowser variable, the $BrowseButton variable, and the $OkButton variable:

```
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    Multiselect = $false # Multiple files can be chosen
    Filter = 'PDFs (*.pdf)|*.pdf' # Specified file types
}

$BrowseButton.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Popup
$BrowseButton.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]16,[System.Int32]212))
$BrowseButton.Name = [System.String]'BrowseButton'
$BrowseButton.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$BrowseButton.TabIndex = [System.Int32]1
$BrowseButton.Text = [System.String]'Browse'
$BrowseButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$BrowseButton.Add_Click({$Dialog = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog(); if($Dialog -eq 'OK') {return $FileBrowser.SelectedPath}}) 

$okButton.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::ForestGreen
$okButton.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]626,[System.Int32]440))
$okButton.Name = [System.String]'okButton'
$okButton.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$okButton.TabIndex = [System.Int32]3
$okButton.Text = [System.String]'OK'
$okButton.Add_Click({echo $File })
$okButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
```

For now, I'll settle for just being able to echo the path using an Add_Click event with the Ok button or something similar. How can I 1) Store the selected file in a variable using the browse button (preferably an add click event), 2) Pass that variable (does it need to be global to work?) to an Add_Click function for the OK button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer to this on a separate forum.

```
$BrowseButton.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Popup
$BrowseButton.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]16,[System.Int32]212))
$BrowseButton.Name = [System.String]'BrowseButton'
$BrowseButton.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]23))
$BrowseButton.TabIndex = [System.Int32]1
$BrowseButton.Text = [System.String]'Browse'
$BrowseButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$BrowseButton.Add_Click({
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog 
$FileBrowser.Filter = 'PDFs (*.pdf)|*.pdf' 
if($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq "Ok"){
    $Script:filename = 'Not found'
    $Script:filename = $TextBox.Text = $FileBrowser.Filename
}})

$TextBox.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]100,[System.Int32]212))
$TextBox.Name = [System.String]'Path'
$TextBox.Size = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]75,[System.Int32]300))
```

If I understand this code correctly, my problem was a couple things. One problem was scoping. The fact that the object is generated in the add click function and the $script scope modifier is added resolves this issue and allows the function here to a be useful elsewhere within the script. The second is telling the script what to do when "ok" (or open) is pressed within the file browser. This is handled with the conditional statement.

Finally, there was an error with the way I've handled running the pdftotext application. I didn't need to run it as an add_click event. I've simply added it to the bottom of my script like so and it DOES in fact accept the variable as an argument.

```
.\Includes\Bin32\pdftotext $filename
```

Ultimately this works for my purposes.